# email form with formspree.io for github.io pages website

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I created a personal portfolio website with a bootstrap theme.

It comes with pre-built PHP form submission, however I am not able to use that since I'm hosting the website on github.io pages.

I deleted the PHP folder/file and configured the  html for formspree. I added the formspree action= attribute as well as the name attributes in all input elements within the form. After all that it's still not working. Please see my code below:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://formspree.io/paulhanna1933@gmail.com" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Email Address" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="Phone Number" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name="Message" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's Working you will try on live server. it redirects Form spree page you don't want that go for AJAX call and use

```
<input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none;"/>
```

_gotcha for avoid re-captcha.